# Yellow Triangle on C Drive after Disabling Secure Boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, security, multi-boot, ubuntu-14.04

I want to dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 on my Windows 10 Thinkpad laptop. From online instructions, I was recommended to disable fast boot and secure boot before I install Ubuntu. After the process of disabling fast boot and secure boot, I noticed that there is a yellow triangle sign with an exclamation mark appearing on my C drive in file explorer.

[image]

This symbol did not appear before I changed the boot settings. My questions are

1) What does this mean? Will this affect anything? Should I be concerned or is there anything I need to fix before proceeding to partition the drive and install Ubuntu?

2) It appears this could be related to BitLocker. Checking BitLocker setting, I see that it is not on. I do not know if it was on before or not but I did not do anything that changed this setting. Since I am quite a noob, could someone explain if or how the changes I made in the boot settings affected BitLocker setting, or if this new notification was caused by something else completely unrelated?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does this mean?

It means Device Encryption is suspended.

> Will this affect anything?

It only means while your files are encrypted the encryption key is accessible.  However, Device Encryption should be disabled, since Ubuntu does not play well with it.

Answer (score 5):

Run this command from elevated command prompt:

`manage-bde -off C:`

This will disable Bitlocker protection for your system drive. You can check your status with this command:

`manage-bde -status C:`